# Stacked plot that display values in a tooltip in markdown document in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, ggvis, googlevis

I need to plot bar charts with stacked values in a `rmarkdown` document. This can be done using ggplot of course like:

```
df1 <- read.csv('Data_New.csv')
df1$year <- factor(df1$year)
ggplot(df1,aes(x = year,y=value, fill = type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +   theme_light()
```

It is easy to insert the following plot in a web document as well. [Example data are here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhekg7yiecsslon/Data_New.csv?dl=0).

[image]

But I do not have the tooltip option which plots generated by `googlevis` have.
My question is: Is there a package/command which would generate stacked plot and display value when clicked on a webpage (generated in markdown)? I am aware of plotly but it's features are not readily available in R. Any other way?

I can reword my question. How can I make the above plot in R using `googlevis` package or otherwise?

Comment: see the [title option](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) in markdown